# Charge renormalization choice in QED

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, quantum-electrodynamics, renormalization, dimensional-analysis

In the lectures on QFT I'm following we define the renormalized QED Lagrangian as

$$\mathcal{L} = \dfrac{1}{4} (F_0)_{\mu\nu} (F_0)^{\mu\nu} + \bar{\psi}_0 (i \bar{\partial} - (m_0)_e) \psi_0 - e_0 \bar{\psi}_0 \gamma^\mu \psi_0 (A_0)_\mu,$$

where we have $(A_0)_\mu \equiv \sqrt{Z_3} A_\mu $, $(\psi_0) \equiv \sqrt{Z_\psi} \psi$, and $e_0 \equiv Z_e e \mu^\epsilon$. The $Z$ are the renormalization constants, $\mu$ is the mass scale of the interaction and $\epsilon$ is a parameter used for dimensional regularisation, satisfying $d = 4 - 2\epsilon$ (where $d$ is the dimension of the problem).

Now, I don't understand why we have such an equality for $e$. Why do we have a factor of $\mu$, the length scale, explicitly present in the renormalized electric charge? And why on earth is it to the power of $\epsilon$, which should be taken to $0$ in the limit?

I haven't seen this renormalization choice anywhere else. Does anyone know why it should be useful?

Comment: In general $d$ dimensions, the coupling $e$ has dimension $[e_0] = \frac{4-d}{2}$. It follows that in $d=4-2\epsilon$, we have $[e_0] = \epsilon$. If we define $e_0 = Z_e e \mu^\epsilon$, then $e$ and $Z_e$ are dimensionless. All the dimensions are accounted for in the factor $\mu^\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is common practice whenever dimensional regularization is used. Simply consider the dimensions of the various terms in $d$ space-time dimensions. As the action $S= \int d^d x \, \mathcal{L}$ is dimensionless, you can read off $$[\mathcal{L}] =d, \quad [A_0]=d/2, \quad [\psi_0]=(d-1)/2, \quad [e_0]=2-d/2, \quad \text{etc.}    $$ With $d=4-2 \epsilon$ you obtain $[e_0]=\epsilon$. As $e$ is supposed to become the *dimensionless*  coupling constant in $d=4$ dimensions and because of $[Z_e]=0$ you introduce the factor $\mu^\epsilon$ (the energy scale $\mu$ has dimension $1$, so  $[\mu^\epsilon]=\epsilon$) in $e_0 = Z_e e \mu^\epsilon$.